# How to understand the word "hang" in the following cases? or is there any word that could replace it?

Tags: meaning

Where it is not practicable to avoid a door opening onto an escape route, for instance with a door leading from a staff room, the door should be **hung** so as to be closed by the stream of people passing in the direction of escape.

Where an outward opening door would prejudice the easy operation of the premises or the safety of staff, for example a door leading from a control room onto a public passageway, consideration should be given to relocating the door or **hanging** the door so that it opens inwards.

Comment: By definition, ***hanging*** is the verb that is used to talk about the installation of doors in doorways.  This is likely because the door literally hangs from its hinges in the door frame.

Comment: @Jim I think I could get the basic idea of it, but I'm translating them and not able to find a proper Chinese verb to say "hang". In the above context, can I actually replace hang with install?

Comment: Yes, you can use *installed/installing*

Comment: @Jim More interestingly what is the past tense here? Whilst *hanged* applies to execution by hanging, pheasants are *hung* (kept for a period of time hanging up before dressing) to improve the quality of the meat. So what happens with a door? Was it *hung* or *hanged*?

Comment: @WS2- Yes, for doors it's *hung*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hang* is more often the jargon of builders, not of safety officers.  I would word it like:

> Where it is not **practical** to avoid a door opening **into** an escape route, for instance with a door leading from a staff room, the door should be **installed** so as to be closed by the stream of people passing **toward** the **emergency exit**.